# strip all from line starting after whitespace

Tags: linux, sed, sh

I have a file with this content:

```
lines
lines
rootdev=UUID=967d8dc3-f595-4a6e-929e-cc89as5a1a2s               /               ext4    defaults,
lines
```

I am searching for one line command which should strip everything in the line `rootdev` after whitespace, so the final content should be like:

```
lines
lines
rootdev=UUID=967d8dc3-f595-4a6e-929e-cc89as5a1a2s
lines
```

Any idea how to do it with one line command? (so I do not need to open nano with this file and do it manually)

I tried with `sed` but it just replaces the word `rootdev`

```
sed -i 's/rootdev//g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt with `sed` can't work because it would just remove `rootdev` string with an empty string. What you need is a tool that matches a pattern and does an action on that whole line for which I think `awk` is more recommended than `sed`.

Using `awk` to match the line to strip off the spaces using `gsub()` should be sufficient,

```
awk '/^rootdev/{ gsub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",$0) }1' file
```

If you are using GNU `awk` with version greater than 4.1.0, you could use its in-place edit option to make the changes dynamically

```
gawk -i inplace '/^rootdev/{ gsub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",$0) }1' file
```

for earlier versions, use a temporary file

```
awk '/^rootdev/{ gsub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",$0) }1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

or use `sponge` from `moreutils`. If its not available in your system do get it on RHEL using `yum install moreutils` or with `apt-get` in Debian.

```
awk '/^rootdev/{ gsub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",$0) }1' file | sponge file
```

Comment: hi, in my case it does not work (file content stays the same).

Comment: what I tried - to use "cut" program and strip everything from char 50. But now I have no idea how to save output of cut to file.

Comment: I solved it with: sudo cut --complement -c50-999 file > file 2&& sudo mv file2 file

Answer (score 1):

First, search for a line beginning with `rootdev=`, and when you find it delete everything after the first whitespace until the end of line.

```
sed -i '/^rootdev=/ s/ .*$//' file
```

Using a capturing group to keep `rootdev=...` part in, and replacing the whole line with it is an option too.

```
sed -i 's/^\(rootdev=[^ ]*\).*$/\1/' file
```

Comment: hi, in my case it does not work (file content stays the same).

Comment: what I tried - to use "cut" program and strip everything from char 50. But now I have no idea how to save output of cut to file.

Comment: I solved it with: sudo cut --complement -c50-999 file > file 2&& sudo mv file2 file

Comment: Both mine and Inian's solutions work with your example. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question accordingly if you want us to help you.